# How to select the corresponding page of row datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to preselect a row in my datatable and I am using the `row('#rowID').select()` function for that. It does select the row but it doesn't select the corresponding page where that row is. 
I know there exists an option displayStart:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "displayStart": 20
} );
```

to start on a specific page, but it requires the number of the row in the source list not the id of that row.
Is there a way how to initialize the page using the rowID?

EDIT: The data is taken from the server, not in client.

Comment: Have you checked out [page.jumpToData()](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/page.jumpToData())?

Comment: looks promising I'll check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`row().show()`](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/row().show()) API method to display page containing required row.

Please note that you need to include additional JS file `//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/api/row().show().js` for this API method to work.

```
table.row(1).show().draw(false);
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/jttcysam/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell that my data are taken from the server not the client. I marked it as correct because it works if data are on client.

Comment: @ArditMeti, it should work with Ajax-sourced data as well if that is what you mean by "data are taken from the server". However it will not if you're using server-side processing data (`serverSide: true`).

Comment: Yea I meant that option `serverSide: true`